# UICollectionView Highligh or Select cell error

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view with sections, when the user did click on a cell, I'm trying to mark the as selected or checked, and then react on the selected cells, but the error I have is:
each section has 12 cells, when I select the cell everything is good I can mark it as checked, but it marks also another cell, it mark cell every 5 cells, if I downgrade the cells per section to 5, everything is ok it marks only 1 cell.
this is my code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 12
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("videoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! VideoCell
    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! VideoCell

    if cell.checked == true {
        cell.uncheck()
    }
    else {
        cell.check()
    }

}
```

Comment: I assume that `check` and `uncheck` update some state variable in the cell class. This won't work because cell objects are reused. You need to track the checked state in your view controller (I suggest an NSMutableIndexSet) and then set/clear the check mark in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

Comment: nop, in the cell I have an image and this function change the imageView image to checked and unchecked, and the checked attribute is just to know if the cell is checked to uncheck it.

Comment: @Paulw is correct. Instead of keeping track inside your cell if it is checked, do it in yourViewController or datasource class. Cells get reused, and as you can see in your own code, if the cell gets reused (cellForRowAtIndexPath), you set nothing to change the cell's state. So if you check lets say cell 1, and it gets reused as cell 6, cell 6 will also be checked.